# In Unity when I write Debug.Log(" ") it has an error saying that there is a difference between UnityEngine.Log and System.Log. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

It says there is an ambiguous difference between UnityEngine.Log and System.Log and won't print anything. How do I fix it?

I am sorry that people didn't like my question. I am just a new game dev looking for help.

Comment: Welcome new user, this is an excellent simple question.  When you are a new programmer, this is tricky indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplest solution is just to always type, in that script:

```
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("yo !!");
```

In general if it tells you "blah blah ..  difference between AAA and BBB ..."

Simply add either AAA. or BBB. in front of the command in question!

(It is usually the "Unity" one you want.)

I wouldn't bother trying to understand it more than that for now, until you are more familiar with it.

It relates to the things you write up the top of the script with "Using...".