# How to check if all objects in an array meet a requirement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of objects of the class Target, and I have a for loop to check a statement on each of them. What I need to do is check if all of the Target scripts are shot down, which I can do by checking the value of the boolean property `hasShotDown`. Then, if all the Target objects in the array return `true` for hasShotDown, the game should end, by stopping the `timer` object.

```
    public Timer timer;

public Target[] targets;

private void Start() {
    targets = gameObject.GetComponents<Target>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

    if (other.gameObject.layer == 9) {
        foreach (Target obj in targets) {
            if (obj.hasShotDown) {
                timer.StopTimer();
                Debug.Log("Stopped Timer and Ended game");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Timer is a reference to another class, which can stop, start and display the timer. Target is another class, which holds hasShotDown. All help is appreciated, let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You often do it like this ...

```
public bool AreAnyRemaining()
{
  foreach .. of your targets
     {
     if NOT shotdown, return TRUE
     }
  return FALSE
}
```

Observe that this call<sup>†</sup> efficiently returns TRUE if one of them has ***NOT*** been shot down.

You can then use this very easily ....

```
OnTriggerEnter ..
   if ( AreAnyRemaining() )
   {
      Debug.Log("play on!");
   }
   else
   {
      THEY ARE ALL SHOT DOWN - end game, etc
   }
```

It's that easy.

You'll see this pattern everywhere in game code.

---

<sup>†</sup> *(The way the code works in the function is called "breakaway" code.  You just look until you find something, then break away and don't bother with the rest.)*

Comment: That looks like a good way to do it. I will try that out now.

Comment: that's pretty much the "standard" way you will see in any game code, enjoy !

Comment: @yellowyears the "breakaway" pattern is common.  note that user RufusL used **the same breakaway pattern** (just within the same block of code, rather than a separate function)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to be working unfortunately. I am not getting the Debug.Log I put in the else statement

Comment: hola @yellowyears a good tip is, add "Debug Log" statements everywhere, so put one at the start of AreAnyRemaining, put one inside the foreach, and, just before you return treu and just before you return false  and so on ...

Comment: Ah yeah, I've pinned that down. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A better tip in my opinion would be starting to [debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) line by line though ;)

Answer (score 7):

```cs
if (targets.All(obj => obj.hasShotDown)) // or .Any to test for ... "any"
{
    timer.StopTimer();
    Debug.Log("Stopped Timer and Ended game");
}
```

Comment: Yes, according to the question. Just change the code to `targets.All(obj => obj.hasShotDown)`

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi my apologies; yes, you're right; I was looking at what the code in the question does, rather than what it *should* do; my bad

Comment: Hi Marc, this looks promising. But Target[] does not contain a definition for All()

Comment: @yellowyears you need `using System.Linq;`

Comment: That worked, unfortunately I am getting another error, `Assets\EndTrigger.cs(22,21): error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'target' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`, I changed it to target from "obj" but that hasn't solved it either.

Comment: hi @yellowyears , I've given you the usual simple way to do this below ...

Comment: you know, it's a bit of a pain for a beginner in Unity / programming to get in to Linq, lambdas etc all at once!  heh!

Comment: To be fair, you should learn about lambdas and Linq before you learn Unity (or MVC or WebApi, etc for that matter).

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi , TBH I don't really see that.  using Linq/lambda is just a shorthand for very old people like you and me!   Surely, the learning hobbyist programmer has to, at first, learn something as simple as the perfect tutorial RufusL has given on how to "see" the algorithm for and write a breakaway loop.  unity is "the" playground of hobbyist programmers who are only grasping the overall aspects of what the hell they are doing!  eg  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63251860/294884

Comment: @Fattie that is probably very true and the fact that OP accepted your answer showed that new OPs mostly want a simple solution they best understand. However, Captain Kenpachi still has a point and in long term I would say that this solution is better to read, shorter and easier to maintain and thereby in long term perspective has the better code quality. OPs should be ready to learn new techniques and coding styles  especially when they are beginners ;) But that's just my opinion ofcourse ^^

Comment: you know @derHugo I'm not totally sure (I really don't know) if it's wise to even use Linq in unity.  (I do it every day, but, I dunno :) )  In some cases (not always) performance is paramount in frame based crap, so, often I would simply not use Linq and write something out longhand, since, I have no time to check (every version of the product) what Linq is or isn't doing.  Again note performance is very rarely a consideration, I'm just saying

Comment: @Fattie In this case here linq does exactly the same thing .. `All` basically iterates through all items and breaks on the first one not matching the condition ;) I see your point ofcourse, there are cases when you can't be sure and don't want to confirm everytime. I've also seen 5 liner Linq expressions that somehow "work" but nobody really knows what they are doing :'D there I fully agree and writing stuff out most of the time doesn't hurt too much ^^

Comment: in fact thanks for telling me what `All` does in this case, good one !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using a normal `foreach` loop as you were doing is to create a variable to indicate that all objects have been shot down, start it out with a `true` value, and then set it to `false` if you find any object that has not been shot down yet:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.layer == 9) 
    {
        bool allObjectsShotDown = true;

        foreach (Target obj in targets) 
        {
            if (!obj.hasShotDown) 
            {
                allObjectsShotDown = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allObjectsShotDown)
        {
            timer.StopTimer();
            Debug.Log("Stopped Timer and Ended game");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really, you just have a separate function, then it's a trivial return for the breakaway - inevitably you have to use the "negative" function in many places.  You always see zillions of calls "AnyRemaining" "AreAnyLeft" "AnyoneStillStanding" in game code  :)

Comment: @Fattie The `System.Linq` extension method `Any()` is the separate function I would normally use, which @MarcGravell already posted. This is just to show how to write it out the "long" way.